# deleting entire row while providing only one input variable

Tags: sql-server-2005

I've a table with entities:
reg_num, user_name, phone_num, designation

I want to write stored procedure to delete the entire data of a row by just entering reg_num value.

```
create proc del @reg_num nchar(10)
as
delete reg_num, user_name, phone_num, designation from nameTable 
where reg_num = @reg_num
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify columns for a delete statement:

```
create proc del @reg_num nchar(10)
as
delete from nameTable 
where reg_num = @reg_num
```

Comment: what if I only want to delete a particular value i.e suppose I only want to delete phone_num?

Comment: you can't 'delete' a single value, update it eg. update nameTable set phone_num = null where reg_num = @reg_num

Answer (score 0):

You only need to specify the table name, no need for the columns listed.

i.e.

```
create proc del @reg_num nchar(10)
as
delete from nameTable 
where reg_num = @reg_num
```

see also:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp

Answer (score 0):

When you delete you must follow the syntax like this :

```
declare @regNum int
set @regnum = 1

delete from [table] where regnum = @regnum
```

In a stored proc, you need to do this :

```
create procedure test (@regnum int) as 
begin
delete from [table] where regnum = @regnum
end
```

Comment: what if I only want to delete a particular value i.e suppose I only want to delete phone_num?